# CakePHP integer field default null failing validation on save() after read() or create()

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, cakephp

**Schema:**

```
vacation_request_denial_reason_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

**Model:**

```
class VacationRequest extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'VacationRequest';
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');
    var $validate = array('employee_id' => array('numeric' => array('rule' => array('numeric'))),
        'approving_supervisor_id' => array('numeric' => array('rule' => array('numeric'))),
        'vacation_request_status_id' => array('numeric' => array('rule' => array('numeric'))),
        'vacation_hours' => array('numeric' => array('rule' => array('numeric'))),
        'vacation_request_denial_reason_id' => array('numeric' => array('rule' => array('numeric'))));
```

**Controller:**

```
function add() {
  if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $this->VacationRequest->create();
    if ($this->VacationRequest->save($this->data)) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

This code fails validation for `vacation_request_denial_reason_id`...

I've narrowed the problem down to whenever I attempt to call `Model->save()` after calling either a `Model->read()` or `Model->create()`. Proven by the fact the code will work if I comment out the `create()` call.

I dare call this a bug. However, I feel like I've experienced this before for integer columns specifically and forgot the work around. Any guidance is appreciated.

#### UPDATE

I should note that `vacation_request_denial_reason_id` is not part of `$this->data` in the form submission. So it's definitely odd that it's failing validation. Furthermore, it is not my intention to use `'allowEmpty' => true` in the validation rule. When it is present in `$this->data`, I want to ensure it is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

In your validation array, try setting the `empty` option to true:

```
'vacation_request_denial_reason_id' => array('numeric' => array('rule' => array('numeric'), 'empty' => true
```

This will allow the value to be empty. I can't remember whether false is the default, but it seems like that might be the case.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to allow empty values. I have updated my original question to ensure this is clear.

Comment: Ah, so you want it to be filled, but it's okay if it's not part of the data structure at all. In that case, use `'required' => false`. Check out [this page of the validation docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1147/required).